# Failed to initialize Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am developing an iOS project (with xcode 8 & swift 3). I have installed firebase pod through cocoapod. This is my pod:

```
target 'myApp' do
   pod 'Firebase', '~> 3.9'
end
```

Then I open myApp.xcworkspace file, the project is opened in Xcode.

Then I try to initialize a firebase instance by:

```
let BASE_URL = "https://myapp-35211.firebaseio.com/"
// ERROR: Cannot call value of non-function type 'module<Firebase>'
let firebase = Firebase(url: "\(BASE_URL)")
```

(I have `import Firebase`)

I am trying to use firebase database.

Why I get the above error?

**====== UPDATE =======**

OK, I followed the steps to initialize Firebase (add my project in Firebase, download the GoogleService-Info.plist & use `FIRApp.configure()`, etc). Now I get this error:

[image]

Why?

My Podfile is like this:

```
target 'myApp' do
   pod 'Firebase', '~> 3.9'
end
```

Does it mean this pod doesn't include `Firebase/Database` ???

**===== UPDATE AGAIN =====**

OK, add `'Firebase/Database'` to **Podfile** solved the above issue, but why `'Firebase'` pod doesn't include `Firebase/Database`? Isn't it a subset of `'Firebase'` pod?

Comment: Have you imported firebase?

Comment: are you calling `FIRApp.configure()` in your appdelegate?

Comment: Also, I think this question may be similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37355824/error-setting-up-firebase-in-xcode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why are you using the base url on your code, because now, when you are setting up your firebase project, you can link your app project with your firebase project passing your `Bundle identifier`.

Take a look on the firebase documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/start

If you do so, then you just need to do 2 steps:

1 - On you `appDelegate` over `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` add:

```
FIRApp.configure()
```

2 - On the class that you want to take your firebase reference you can do:

```
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
```

This way you will have on `ref` the reference to the root of your firebase database

Comment: I did the steps for initialization. When I use `FIRDatabase.database().reference()`, I get error "Use of unresolved identifier FIRDatabase", why? I have imported Firebase. Please see my update.

Comment: Ok, try to import FirebaseDatabase. If it doesn't work, so then add to your Podfile pod 'Firebase/Database'

Comment: Yep, add 'Firebase/Database' to Podfile solved the issue, but why 'Firebase' pod doesn't include 'Firebase/Database'? Isn't it a subset of 'Firebase' pod?

Comment: I think that after the last update that they made, the modularized the pods. And now you have a pod for each feature, like: database, storage and others. When you add just the Firebase you only get the configure part of it. Could you vote up my answer lol, I would be thankful for that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your iOS App to Firebase. If you haven't done this yet, open the Firebase console, choose your project and add your App, the initialization is guided.

You also need to add the `Firebase/Database` pod if you want to use the database ... check out the guide https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/start